# Group Column values and avoid N/a's in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
Date     Value   Gen
16  Mar   100    Gen1
16  Mar   9      Gen2
12  Mar   15     Gen1
12  Mar   18     Gen2
```

I have tried using dcast and the group by function but I don't think this works to get what I need.

The result I am looking for is:

```
Date1     Gen1  Gen2      
12 Mar    100   15              
16 Mar    9     18
```

Note: Dates values are combined and each Gen Value becomes a column. The values are show in the this table as above. There should be no N/a's as each data point is available).

I have tried group by:
Code:

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>% group_by(Date1, Value) %>%
mutate(id= paste("new_col_",row_number())) %>% 
ungroup() %>%
spread(id, Value)
```

Result:

```
Date1  Gen1  Gen2  `new_col_ 1`
<fct>  <chr> <chr> <fct>           
12_Mar Gen1  NA    100         
12_Mar NA    Gen2    NA    Gen4  15          
8_Mar  NA    Gen2  NA    NA    9           
8_Mar  NA    NA    Gen3  NA    15
```

I have tried dcast which has given me a similar result.

```
example <- dcast(df,Value + Date1 ~ Gen)

Value  Date1    Gen1   Gen2
100    16 Mar   Gen1   <NA>
15     12 Mar   Gen1   <NA>
18     12 Mar   <NA>   Gen2
9      16 Mar   <NA>   Gen2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `spread`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(aa, Gen, Value)
#     Date Gen1 Gen2
#1 12  Mar   15   18
#2 16  Mar  100    9
```

---

Or using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(aa), Date ~ Gen, value.var = 'Value')
```

#### data

```
aa <- structure(list(Date = c("16  Mar", "16  Mar", "12  Mar", "12  Mar"
), Value = c(100L, 9L, 15L, 18L), Gen = c("Gen1", "Gen2", "Gen1", 
"Gen2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```